# How to pass parameter to url?

Tags: magento2

I tried,

I got current url -

```
$current_url =  $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

In phtml file I called parameter

```
<a href="<?php echo $current_url."test/param/1"; ?>">Test</a>
```

Page not found 404 error I am getting.

Link is working perfectly but while passing parameter it is giving 404 error.

Answer (score 6):

You can try by below method. Queries will be passed after appending **?**.

```
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

UrlInterface $urlBuilder

$this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

$queryParams = [
    'oid' => base64_encode($data['order_id']),
    'cid' => base64_encode($data['customer_id'])
];

$this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('controller/index', ['_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $queryParams]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create URL by `$block->getUrl('routeid/controller/action',['param'=>'value'])`.
This is magento's default function so no need to create this function in block.
Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: how to access this value in controller?

Comment: you can get this like this. `$this->getRequest()->getParam("param_name")`

Answer (score 2):

Better to create a block class which extends to

```
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template
```

and create a getUrl() function like below.

```
public function getUrl($param)
{
    return $this->getUrl('modulename/controller_name/action_class_name', ['param' => $param]);
}
```

and then call it from your template like

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(1); ?>">Test</a>
```

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: getUrl($param) should be compatible with Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getUrl

Answer (score 1):

First understand how router work. It is taking from your layout and `router.xml` file.

first you can check layout. `namespace/modulename/view/frontend/layout/modulename_index_index.xml`

`modulename_index_index.xml` first one is module name, 2nd one controller name and third name is index.php file will execute.

also check your router in `etc\frontend\routes.xml`frontName="test". So test is frontend name.

in your example controller name is missing. example index is your controller call  `<a href="<?php echo $current_url."test/index/param/1"; ?>">Test</a>`

it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2.4.5-p1,  in Block, we can get a URL with a query string like the one below.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Custom extends Template
{
    /**
     * Get result url
     *
     * @return string $resultUrl
     */
    public function getResultUrl()
    {   $queryParams = [
            'test' => '123'
        ];

        $params =[
            '_secure' => true,
            '_query' => $queryParams
        ];

        $resultUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'checkout', 
            $params
        );

        return $resultUrl;
    }

}
```

In the template file write like below.

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Block\Custom $block
 */
$resultUrl = $block->getResultUrl();
?>
<div id="test">
  <form action="<?= $resultUrl ?>;"></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

From template file:

```
$block->getUrl('frontname/path/controllername', ['_query' => ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']]);
```

From Controller file:

```
$this->_url->getUrl('frontname/path/controllername', ['_query' => ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']]);
```

Note: No need to define $this->_url in construct of controller as its auto defined in parent classes ( \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action .. )